# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data what is wrong here?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have searched for that error and looked up many posts.. but i still can't figure out what is wrong with this code here:

my ajax call:

```
function myCall3() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax3.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response){
      alert(response[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

my mysql/php code:

```
<?php


// QUERY NEW VINE
$array = array();
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 9";
$result = mysql_query($myquery)
OR die("Error: $myquery <br>".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  $currentid = "$row->id";
  $currentname = "$row->name";
  $currenturl = "$row->url";
  $currentimage = "$row->image";
  $array[] =     array('id'=>$currentid,'url'=>$currenturl,'name'=>$currentname,'image'=>$currentimage);

}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

when i alert the error it says:

> SyntaxError: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overwriting $array in your loop, and then echoing it out too soon.

```
$array =    array('id'=>$currentid,'url'=>$currenturl,'name'=>$currentname,'image'=>$currentimage);

echo json_encode($array);

}
```

you should push each row to the $array variable, and then json_encode outside the loop.

```
$array = array();
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 9";
$result = mysql_query($myquery)
OR die("Error: $myquery <br>".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$currentid = "$row->id";
$currentname = "$row->name";
$currenturl = "$row->url";
$currentimage = "$row->image";
$array[] =  array('id'=>$currentid,'url'=>$currenturl,'name'=>$currentname,'image'=>$currentimage);

}

echo json_encode($array);
```

then your javascript callback will need to expect an array, not an object, i.e.

```
console.log(response[0]);
```

note: you could just push $row directly onto $array of you wanted to.

Comment: When i use this code, how would i alert all the urls in js for example? I am just producing errors -.-

Comment: what error?  what do you get when you log response and response[0]?  It should just all be straightforward array / object notation at this point.

Comment: When i log response[0] it says: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: what about response then?  start at the beginning if you have to.  this is basic debugging 101.  what do you see in your developer tools?  Is it valid JSON?  (use jsonlint.com)

Comment: jsonlint says: Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['

Comment: it would probably help if you showed your updated code now.  it sounds like it's just something small at this point.

Comment: @MarcSter are you getting any errors in PHP?  What is the full response?  Both in the network tab and when you console.log(response). I think there might be an extra parenthesis on this line $array[] =.  Please provide the dump of console.log

Comment: Ok there was a typo in my code.. now it returns "[object Object] for response[0]

Comment: @MarcSter in chrome developer tools, if you actually use console.log that should show you the entire object and all it's properties and values.  i would get in the habit of using the console when developing instead of alert. anyway, looks like you are good to take it from here then.

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning.. so much stuff that i don't know. But you helped me a lot. Finally figured it out.Thanks!

Comment: @MarcSter awesome!  glad to hear it.  also, I just happen to use Chrome, but any modern browser should have similar developer / debugging options.  Firefox has Firebug, for example.

Comment: Yes i am using Firebug. I already have worked with that for my html and css stuff, but i never realized using console.log for debugging lol, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result) {
   $newArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Then, in JS you have to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks like this:

```
{"id":123,"url":"http://.../","name":"Blah","image":"blah.png"}{"id":456,.....
```

That doesn't look right to me :p

It looks like your JavaScript is expecting just one row, so try `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: yes it works with limit1, but the thing is i want to get 9 :).. do i may have to change the variables to arrays in the ajax call?

Comment: @marc collect the results into an array and stringify and echo it at once.